# SQL Server Table change in one App not showing in other App

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have two MVC applications that both use the same SQL Server database and table. One of them has updated the table, and shows the new value as does SQL Server, but the other app still picks up the old value before it was changed even if it is restarted.
I have checked and they both use the same database in the connection string. What might be causing this issue and how might I resolve it so that the second app uses the new value?

Comment: That is not what's happening.  Check that you don't have a table with the same name in a different schema, and double-check everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick response David Browne, I had checked everything several times and I have just managed to resolve this by deleting the IE cache information. When I did this it displayed the current information. It looks like it was the View that had cached the extracted field and was using this instead of going back to the database. Deleting the cache history resolved this.